# I've got interesting problem from Russian school physics olympiad

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, capacitance

[image: Ho]

I've been trying to solve this really hard problem (only for me maybe :) from Russian school olympiad for 1 week and I stucked. I tried to make some equivalent electric circuits, but I always end up on finding the capacitance of a parallel plate capacitor with different areas (how I understand there is no easy way to calculate it).

I have no solution for this problem, but I've got problem author's answer WATCH OUT SPOILER:

$C=\frac{6Sε0}{7d}$

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Hi @VolodymyrKravchuk, and welcome to Physics SE! Please take a few moments to read our [help page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help) and in particular our policy on [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/715/106502). We prefer questions here that are asking a specific, conceptual question, rather than asking for the solution to a complete problem.